# Google Cloud deploy PHP/Symfony webapp with Docker

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, php-8

I am using Google Cloud and I am trying to deploy this [repository](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius-Standard).

This is the [docker-compose.prod.yml](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius-Standard/blob/1.12/docker-compose.prod.yml)
And the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius-Standard/blob/1.12/Dockerfile)

Everything goes perfect: the build stage is finish without any error.

But the problem appears on the deploying stage: I get this error:

> The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port
> defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable. Logs for this
> revision might contain more information

I am new to Docker. I don't know where the port 8080 is being defined from the application.

Does anyone knows when in my docker files is this defined or how can I fix this error and deploy the application.

I have tried:

1. gcloud run deploy ds-creative --source .
2. gcloud run deploy ds-creative --source . --port=8080
3. Creating a Cloud Run service from a GitHub repository.
4. Creating a firewall rule to open port 8080

And in all of them I get the same error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on this documentation on [troubleshooting Cloud Run issues](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#container-failed-to-start), you need to rule out potential causes first:

1. Verify that you can [run your container image locally](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/testing/local).
2. Check if your container is listening for requests on the expected port as documented in the [container runtime contract](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract#port). Your container must listen for incoming requests on the port that is defined by Cloud Run and provided in the `PORT` environment variable. See [Configuring containers](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/containers) for instructions on how to specify the port.
3. Check if your container is listening on all network interfaces, commonly denoted as `0.0.0.0`.
4. Verify that your container image is compiled for 64-bit Linux as required by the [container runtime contract](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract#languages).

   - Note: If you build your container image on a ARM based machine, then it might not work as expected when used with Cloud Run. To solve this issue, [build your image using Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/building/containers#builder).
5. Use Cloud Logging to [look for application errors in `stdout` or `stderr` logs](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/logging). You can also [look for crashes captured in Error Reporting](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/error-reporting).

   You might need to update your code or your revision settings to fix errors or crashes. You can also [troubleshoot your service locally](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/local-troubleshooting).

You can also check this [similar stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74359729/the-user-provided-container-failed-to-start-and-listen-on-the-port-defined-provi).