# Unable to Deploy MLFlow On Cloud Run and Connect to CloudSQL via Unix Socket Connection

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, mlflow, cloud-sql-proxy

I am trying to deploy MLflow on Cloud Run. The Cloud Run Service needs to be connected to CloudSQL. I am trying to establish the connection by running CloudSQL proxy in the same docker container and connecting ML flow with the same.
In the logs I am able to see that the CloudSQL proxy is able to connect to the Cloud SQL instance but logs for Mlflow server are not there, nor I am able to access MLflow via UI.

On deploying it on Cloud Run, I am getting this error:

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y bash && apt-get install -y wget gnupg2 && \
    wget https://dl.google.com/cloudsql/cloud_sql_proxy.linux.amd64 -O cloud_sql_proxy && \
    chmod +x cloud_sql_proxy && \
    pip install mlflow pymysql

FROM gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.22.0

# Copy the service account JSON file to the container
COPY ./<path-to-credential-file> .

# Expose the default Cloud SQL port
EXPOSE 5000

ENV INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME=<instance-connection-name>
ENV MYSQL_USER=<username>
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD=<password>
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=<database_name>

# Start the Cloud SQL proxy
CMD ["/cloud_sql_proxy", "-instances=$INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME=tcp:0.0.0.0:3306", "-credential_file=<credential-file>", "-dir=/cloudsql & mlflow server \
    --default-artifact-root gs://<gcs-bucket-uri> \
    --host 0.0.0.0 --port 5000 \
    --backend-store-uri mysql+pymysql://$MYSQL_USER:$MYSQL_PASSWORD@localhost:3306/$MYSQL_DATABASE?unix_socket=/cloudsql/$INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME"]
```

````
The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.```
````

Comment: Any reason why you're not just using the built-in Cloud SQL integration? Cloud Run will run the Proxy for you in that approach.

Comment: @enocom, acc. to your approach my steps should be - 

- Deploy a Cloud Run Service
- Then, add CloudSQL Instance in the configuration

IMO, these steps work when we write code for the application from scratch. In my case, I am uploading a third party Docker Image (Mlflow) and starting a command to start the server which I think is not able to set up connection. 
For unix sockets, one has to set up the code which I am not able
For public IP address, I am not able to get the URL/IP address of the Cloud Run service as it won't deploy unless it is able to set up connection

Comment: Does mlflow accept a Unix socket? If so, you could configure the Cloud SQL integration and just point mlflow at the Unix socket (/cloudsql/myproj:region:myinst).

Comment: I am not sure about this and need your suggestion. 
In the MLflow docs, the format for backend store URI is as follows:
<dialect>+<driver>://<username>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<database>
Will it support only IP address and port of the CloudSQL instance?

Answer (score 0):

This error is usually caused by the container unable to listen to the incoming HTTP requests on the port defined by Cloud Run and provided in the `$PORT` environment variable. By default, requests are sent to port `8080` but you can [configure Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/containers#command-line) to send requests to the port of your choice.

You can check this documentation on [troubleshooting container failing to start](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#container-failed-to-start) especially number **2**:

> Check if your container is listening for requests on the expected port as documented in the [container runtime contract](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract#port). Your container must listen for incoming requests on the port that is defined by Cloud Run and provided in the `PORT` environment variable. See [Configuring containers](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/containers) for instructions on how to specify the port.

You may also refer to these community questions as your references:

- [The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74359729/the-user-provided-container-failed-to-start-and-listen-on-the-port-defined-provi)
- [Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55662222/container-failed-to-start-failed-to-start-and-then-listen-on-the-port-defined-b)
- [cloudrun an error while deploying from Artifact Registry](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Serverless/cloudrun-an-error-while-deploying-from-Artifact-Registry/m-p/407292)